# Accidentally set chmod 777 to /var/log

Tags: logs, chmod, logrotate

So I've set chmod 777 -R to /var/log on Raspbian and now I get some errors when logrotate runs.
The errors are like:

> error: skipping "/var/log/apt/term.log" because parent directory has insecure permissions (It's world writable or writable by group which is not "root") Set "su" directive in config file to tell logrotate which user/group should be used for rotation.

Is there a way to set it back to the default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely set perms to 755 for directories and 644 for file:

```
# find /var/log -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
# find /var/log -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

More secure (with access for root only):

```
# find /var/log -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
# find /var/log -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
```

Comment: Shorthand: `chmod -R u=rwX,g=rX,o=rX /var/log`, respectively `chmod -R u=rwX,g=,o= /var/log`.

Answer (score 2):

Files located in `/var/log/` on raspbian have usually `-rw-r-----`  permissions which means `chmod 640` will put the correct permissions back.

For example, `/var/log/apt/term.log` has the following permissions set:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root adm      0 Nov  1 06:25 term.log
```

Other files under `/var/log/` have the following permissions set:

```
-rw-r----- 1 root adm    214421 Nov 13 10:01 auth.log
-rw-r----- 1 root adm  16903470 Nov 12 06:25 auth.log.1
```

To set the correct permissions on these files use `find` as follows:

```
find /var/log/ -type f -exec chmod 640 {} +
```

For directories, you can use this:

```
find /var/log -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
```

The command `find` will walk through the `/var/log` directory and based on the `type` you pass to it, correct permissions are applied.

Comment: The result of the command is _find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter_ but it helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @sOnt I saw I had an extra `-` there as `-f` but corrected it. Glad it helped you